# Why can't I transfer a file via wget (FTP) using exec() function in PHP?

Tags: ftp, wget

Put simply, I can't work out why the code below won't carry out a file transfer? I have been assured by the sysadmin staff on the remote server that there are no permissions/firewall issues that could be affecting it and that the login details are correct.

I've logged file output using `-O` and the resulting file (`--ftp-user=ITParts`) is blank. What could be wrong?

```
exec('wget -o --ftp-user="xxxx" --ftp-password="xxxx"  \
    ftp.eurosimm.com/StocklistDealSOss.csv \
    /home/design/public_html/itpartsandspares/');
```

Comment: url (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) are in the form protocol://host/path, for you, it should be ftp://ftp.eurosimm.com/PATH/Stock. I assume you sample is a mistake in copy/paste ?

Comment: on second thought, have you tried `wget ...` on command line ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `ftp_get` function?

Comment: Where is wget located? (`type wget`) and is the path in the once `exec()` searches for binaries?

Comment: You do not state the log filename after the `-o` option and you do not use the `-O` option before the output file name.

Comment: In order for this Q to be further worked you'll need to address the Q's that everyone has asked above. Specifically does the `wget` command work from the command line? Also is the `wget` cmd. accessible in your PHP script via it's `$PATH`? Lastly make sure that `wget` is making use of an appropriate protocol,` `ftp://`. When left bare like you have, I believe it defaults to `http://`. Also why do this using a sub shell running `wget`? PHP has libraries for doing this type of request.

Comment: Why are you logging to a file called `--ftp-user=blah`? Makes no sense, since you're then not passing an ftp user name.

Comment: I think he can easily verify if `wget` is in the path with a simple php file like `<?php passthru("sh -c 'wget --version' 2>&1") ?>` assuming `sh` is in the path, still the hosting may have disabled `exec` and/or `passthru` functions for security reasons. Passwords on command line? You're gonna regret :)

Comment: wget was installed successfully and I was transferring a file from a different server using the same method without any problem but without -o if i remember correctly. I originally tried ftp_get without any success and so I suspected that that extension might not have been installed. However I have tried it again using ftp_get and it is now working. So thanks to Barmar for making me try it again!